# Laravel 5.5 Notification Set Null in database

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to set the notifications for a user. But when i the method try to set data into database in my RequestinfoController it's always send null :  the user_id have value

Xampp
PHP Version 7.2.5
Apache/2.4.33 
Laravel 5.5

```
/* Controller */
 public function acceptRequest($employer_id, $user_id)
  {
      $requestinfo = Requestinfo::where(['employer_id'=> $employer_id, 'user_id'=>$user_id])->first();
      $employer = Employer::find($employer_id);

          $requestinfo->update(['accepted'=> 1]);
          if($requestinfo){
            $employer->notify(new AcceptedRequest($user_id));

            return alert_msg('success', 'update_success' ,'requestinfo');
          }
      return alert_msg('error', 'update_error' ,'requestinfo');
  }
```

this the Notification code

```
/* Notification */
class AcceptedRequest extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $user_id;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->$user_id = $user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            "user_id"=> $this->user_id,
            "message"=> "request info accepted",
            "icon"=> "<i class='fas fa-check-square'></i>"
        ];
    }
}
```

//resualt in database

{"user_id":null,"message":"request info accepted","icon":"</i>"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you initialized the object, the variables are set to null. That's why you are getting `null` as the `user_id`. And the real issue lies in the constructor method-

```
 public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->$user_id = $user_id;
    }
```

We don't access object variables preceding with `$`, you need to change it to `$this->user_id = $user_id;`

`$this->$user_id` is basically instantiating a **Double Variable** which means the value of `$user_id` becomes a variable.

So if the value of `$user_id` is say `10`, then `$this->$user_id` results in `$this->10` and this doesn't make any sense.

However if the value is say `dummy_value` the `$this->$user_id` results in `$this->dummy_value` and there could be a object variable named `dummy_user`.

Double variable is a really powerful feature if used properly.